# South American Week

Tags: discussion, events, questions

Someone pointed out that we lack questions on South America.  As some of my favourite countries are there, I agreed.  For the next few days I've created events that will be announced in the chat room to try and encourage people to ask questions about certain countries, as it will hopefully draw some more traffic from those regions, and give us a more worldly bias - most of our questions are Europe, North America and Asia oriented.

It's experimental, let me know what you think of it - whether such events are a good idea or not.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Sorry. System messages are not supposed to be used for anything other than major events that affect the whole site: site elections, downtime due to maintenance, etc. Meta is your best bet; if a mod tags it as "featured" it will have a good chance of appearing frequently in the "visit meta" ad in the sidebar on the main site.

Comment: @mindcorrosive deleted his comment? Anyway, as per http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/493/topic-challenge/495#495 comments and this thread, we've stuck to an event and meta posts, and will see how it goes.

Comment: hmm...okay. There's nothing wrong with asking if you can bend a rule a little; I'm very happy you guys asked before doing it. There's no reason to delete the record of it. Anyway, thanks for sticking to the event and meta; hope that helps get some exposure for this event.

Answer (score 5):

If we're going to get thematic weeks, we could also fill in and improve the tag wikis and descriptions for the relevant countries.

Comment: Yes! But please try to follow our "standards". Don't just define the tags but try to say what makes it relevant for travel. It can be hard in such short space. Start with a capital letter and end with a full stop. Don't include the word "is" because it triggers an ugly text shortening function when you look at the Tags page. See how it looks on the Tags page after your edit.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea and very similar to the call of topics. Maybe we could use the topics proposed there fore the next events after the south american week. For example a tiny countries week, a nudism week, etc.

Comment: good thinking.  We'll see how this goes, and then after Christmas start taking them from the topics call list, assuming it goes ok.

Comment: Nudism week sounds even better than Naked Mondays!

Comment: It's Ecuador day today people, let's see some of those questions ;)